# Diferencia entre "plañir" y "llorar"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, significado

En una conversación ha salido hoy un término que me ha fascinado:

> **[plañidero, ra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TL7hQhw)**
>
> De *plañido*.
>
> 1. adj. Lloroso y lastimero.
> 2. f. Mujer llamada y pagada que iba a llorar a los entierros.

La segunda acepción es la que me ha sorprendido, la verdad es que no sabía que existiera un oficio así (aunque el uso de *iba* en vez de *va* indica que es algo que ya no se hace).

El caso es que de ahí he visto que en español existe el verbo *plañir*:

> **[plañir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TLFeZZB)**
>
> Del lat. *plangĕre*.
>
> 1. intr. Gemir y llorar, sollozando o clamando. U. t. c. prnl.

En contraposición tenemos el verbo *llorar*:

> **[llorar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NVzTcUw)**
>
> Del lat. *plorāre*.
>
> 1. intr. Derramar lágrimas. U. t. c. tr.

Parece que el verbo *llorar* es más simple que *plañir* en cuanto a sus implicaciones, puesto que simplemente "derramar lágrimas" no implica tener un sentimiento de pena o tristeza, como parece implicar *plañir*. Tal y como lo veo, plañir implica llorar, pero llorar no implica plañir.

Mirando otros diccionarios, he visto que tanto el español como el portugués y el francés optaron por derivados de *plorāre*, mientras que el italiano se decantó por un derivado de *plangĕre*, no sé si es porque los italianos son más expresivos. Y en el caso del español, se usa el derivado *llorar* incluso aunque la situación merezca el uso de *plañir*, que ha quedado en desuso (aunque no esté marcado como tal, yo nunca lo he visto usado salvo en palabras derivadas).

¿Estoy en lo cierto en cuanto a las diferencias entre ambos verbos, o la diferencia es otra? ¿Se usó en el pasado el verbo *plañir* cuando la situación lo merecía por encima del verbo *llorar*? ¿Cuándo quedó en desuso el verbo *plañir*?

Comment: A mi me hace gracia esta acepción de llorar: *2. intr. Manar de los ojos un líquido.* ¿Como que un liquido? ¿no valía con la primera acepción "derramar lagrimas"? ¿Si sangro de los ojos también lloro? ¿Qué otros líquidos pueden manar de los ojos?

Comment: Sólo quiero aportar que la palabra "**plañidera**" no está *totalmente* en desuso a día de hoy. Las **plañideras** siguen existiendo en un contexto muy concreto, en el **[Entierro de la Sardina](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entierro_de_la_sardina)**. Ejemplo de uso actual: [Récord de plañideras en el entierro de la sardina en la playa de Riazor](https://www.lavozdegalicia.es/noticia/coruna/2001/03/01/record-planideras-entierro-sardina-playa-riazor/0003_446062.htm).

Comment: No sólo expresiones figuradas, sino casi literalmente: si hacéis una búsqueda rápida en Google de "Virgen que llora sangre" tendréis miles de resultados. Hay referencias a imágenes, supuestos milagros, etc.

Comment: Concuerdo con @Alicia. A mi se me hace muy natural el uso de plañidera y no está tan en desuso como se podría pensar. Un ejemplo del uso actual de la palabra [Plañideras de izquierda compiten en cursilería para despedir a Galeano](http://www.libertaddigital.com/cultura/libros/2015-04-13/la-izquierda-cursi-despide-a-galeano-de-mi-vida-no-mia-a-la-voz-de-acantilado-1276545448/)

Comment: @blonfu : https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemolacria : **Hemolacria** es una condición física, que causa que la persona produzca lágrimas que están parcialmente compuestas de sangre. Puede manifestarse como lágrimas que contienen algunos tonos rojizos a parecer estar hechas enteramente de sangre.
La hemolacria es un síntoma de numerosas enfermedades,​ y puede ser indicativo de un tumor en el aparato lagrimal. Es provocado a menudo por factores locales como conjuntivitis bacterial, daños ambientales o heridas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tal como indica la definicion, plañir consiste en *"Gemir **y** llorar"*. Nótese la conjunción: además de derramar lágrimas, es necesario emitir sonidos lastimeros, gemidos, lamentos.

Para definir esto, hoy en día se usa más la palabra **llanto**:

> **[llanto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NUHokpl)**
>
> 1. m. Efusión de lágrimas acompañada frecuentemente de lamentos y sollozos.

Aunque ciertamente no tiene la misma fuerza que *plañir*, motivo por el cual éste se reserva para referirse a llantos exagerados, como los de las plañideras en los entierros.

Intentando responder a la segunda parte de tu pregunta, esta es la frecuencia de uso del verbo *plañir* según el CORDE:

[image: © yo]

Puede verse que en los siglos XV y XVI se usaba el verbo como tal verbo (*plañen*, *plañían*, *plañendo* etc.), de manera relativamente frecuente, y en varias ocasiones contrapuesto a *llorar*: *"plañendo fuert e llorando"*, *"plañja & lloraua"* *. En cambio, los usos sustantivados (*plañidera*, *plañido* etc.) eran los menos.
A partir del s. XVII empieza a decaer su uso, siendo prácticamente inexistente en el s. XVIII.
En los ss. XIX y XX, se produce una reaparición del término, pero usándose sobre todo como sustantivo. El uso propiamente verbal se puede considerar testimonial si tenemos en cuenta la abundancia de obra escrita en estos siglos, respecto de los siglos XV y XVI.

<sub>* Eso no sale en la gráfica, pero es lo que he observado.</sub>